# class operator with result of Extended type does not work in BDS2006?

Tags: delphi, operator-overloading, delphi-2006

If I try to compile the following code I got an error message "E2010 Incompatible types: 'Extended' and 'TMyRec'" for the last line (E := R):

```
type
  TMyRec = record
    class operator Implicit(Rec: TMyRec) : Integer;
    class operator Implicit(Rec: TMyRec) : Extended;
  end;

class operator TMyRec.Implicit(Rec: TMyRec) : Integer;
begin
  Result := 1;
end;

class operator TMyRec.Implicit(Rec: TMyRec) : Extended;
begin
  Result := 1;
end;

var
  R : TMyRec;
  B : Byte;
  E : Extended;

begin
  B := R; //this is OK
  E := R; //E2010 Incompatible types: 'Extended' and 'TMyRec'
end.
```

I asked a friend to try to compile it in XE - the compilation succeeded. So is this a bug in BDS2006? Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed a compiler defect. The only way to fix it is to upgrade to a version of the compiler that resolves the defect. If you cannot do that you'll just need to write your code in a different way.

FWIW, in my view, it is invariably a mistake to use `Extended`. This type is non-standard and only exists on x86. At some point in the future if you move to x64 you will find that `Extended` is mapped onto `Double`. Furthermore, the alignment of the type leads to poor memory access performance and programs that store data as `Extended` rather than `Double` tend to be noticeably slower.

Comment: Thank you also for the extra info about `Extended`. Anyway in this case the exact type is irrelevant, because the compiler fails when choosing any real type.